# Not to match start/end points of closed curves when adding a bevel?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I have a closed curve and need to ad some skin to it. I added a profiled bevel. As you can see in the image, the section where the curve closes is not beveled correctly. It is not matching in tilt.

How can I make a closed curve to be beveled smoothly even in the closing section?

[image: End and start points don't match when beveled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the two points and connect them by pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> key, which creates a segment between those points.

Then select several of your surrounding points (or all of them, depending on what works better in your case) and select *Smooth Curve Tilt* under *Control Points*.

This will close the open area and the curve tilt should be smooth.

PS: If the open spot is indeed one created by a cyclic spline, then you cannot/do not need to connect the two points and then you need to align the tilt at the end points manually and smooth the tilt afterwards.

[image]

Comment: My curve was made from a closed mesh. I think that's why your first method did not work. But the second method worked very well. A couple of manual tilts/smooth tilts did the trick. Thanks.